# Spectral Measures: Adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is only Q&A!*

*(See the hint: [SE: Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Regard the domain:
$$\int|f(\lambda)|^2\mathrm{d}\|E(\lambda)\varphi\|^2<\infty$$

And the calculus:
$$\langle f(E)\varphi,\chi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{C} f(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\langle E(\lambda)\varphi,\chi\rangle$$

Then one has:
$$f(E)^*=\overline{f}(E)$$

How to prove this?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this? It is not a frequently asked question, is it?

Comment: @wythagoras: Yeaah but I need these lemmata for other real problems.

Comment: How does that answer my question? Math Stack Exchange is not a storage place for your results.

Comment: Mhhh yaa I know :/ But see the hint: [SE: Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Oh, in that case, nevermind my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regard the sets:
$$\Omega_n:=\{|f|\leq n\}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$1_n:=\chi_{\Omega_n}\quad f_n:=f1_n$$

By dominated convergence:
$$\langle f(E)\varphi,\psi\rangle=\lim_n\langle f_n(E)\varphi,\psi\rangle=\lim_n\langle\varphi,\overline{f_n}(E)\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\overline{f}(E)\psi\rangle$$

They extend by:
$$1_n(E)f(E)^*=1_n(E)^*f(E)^*\subseteq(f(E)1_n(E))^*=f_n(E)^*=\overline{f_n}(E)$$

By monotone convergence:
$$\int|\overline{f}|^2\mathrm{d}\nu_\psi=\lim_n\int|\overline{f_n}|^2\mathrm{d}\nu_\psi=\lim_n\|\overline{f_n}(E)\psi\|^2\\
=\|1_n(E)f(E)^*\psi\|^2\leq\|f(E)^*\psi\|^2<\infty$$

Concluding the assertion.